# GUI class not displaying anything on monitor

Tags: java, user-interface

I am new to GUI and I would like to know why this code is not displaying anything. Keep in mind that the code is not complete and bear with me guys the code is a bit long.

```
//imports

public class SudokuGame extends Frame{

private SudokuBoard sb = new SudokuBoard(this);

/**
 * a button to restart game
 */
private Button b = new Button("Restart");

/**
 * 9 x 9 buttons to store the numbers used in the game
 */
private Button[][] grid= new Button[9][9];

/**
 * TextField used to store the remaining empty blocks
 */
private TextField t;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param ssm
 */
public SudokuGame(SomeSudokuMatrix ssm) {

    /**
     * sets window's name
     */

    super( "Sudoku" );

    /**
     * sets background color
     */

    setBackground( Color.WHITE );





    /**
     * adds SudokuBoard to the SudokuGame which extends frame
     */

    add( sb, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    /**
     * initialize the remaining blocks to TextField
     */

    t = new TextField("Remain:" + sb.getEmpty()); 

    /**
     * new panel
     */

    Panel p = new Panel();

    /**
     * sets panel size to 100 x 10
     */

     p.setSize(100,10);

    /**
     * sets restart button size to 10 x 5 and location to 48, 5
     */

    b.setBounds(48,5,10,5);  

    /**
     * adds restart button to the Panel
     */

    p.add( b );

    /**
     * adds panel to south 
     */

    add( p, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    /**
     * adds ActionListner to restart button
     */

    b.addActionListener( sb );


    /**
     * adds TextField to the Panel
     */

    p.add(t); 

    /**
     * Sets the TextField size to 10 x 5 and location to 53, 5
     */

    t.setBounds(53,5,10,5);

    /**
     * adds the buttons that hold the values
     */

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){

            grid[i][j]=new Button(null);
            add(grid[i][j]);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Automatically resizing
     */

    pack();

    /**
     * Shows SudokuGame 
     */

    setVisible(true);

    /**
     * Shows the Panel
     */

    p.setVisible(true);       
 }

 /**
 * sets the label of the button
 * 
 * @param s   String to add to the button
 * @param i   the position
 * @param j   the position
 */

public void setText(String s, int i, int j){

    /**
     * if the button is not empty sets the label of the button
     */

    if(!s.equals("-1")){
    grid[i][j].setLabel(s); 
    }
}  //to do: change TextField when filling empty block

public void setText(String s){

    t.setText(s);
}
}
```

This is the GUI class (the frame) without the canvas or the actionlisteners or any other classes that run the game.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error, does it compile but nothing happens? Are you following some kind of tutorial? More information will help you get a better answer.

Comment: When I run it, it compiles and run but nothing happens. This is an assignment for my computing class, so I am following the assignment specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written

```
private Button[][] grid= new Button[9][9];
```

It should be

```
 private Button[][] grid= new Button[9][];
```

Next you have directly started adding Button from grid array as:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Which is wrong and Because of this it throws NullPointerException. Please see Console of IDE.
Solution is to first instantiate grid array as follows:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    grid[i]=new Button[9];
  }

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      grid[i][j]=new Button("SomeLabel");
    }
}
```

After  initializing grid array, add buttons to frame as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        add(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea my bad I forgot to initialize them but I had the problem before adding the buttons and after I initiate them I have the same problem, but thanks for the catch. One more thing why should I initiate the array with [9][] instead of [9][9] shouldn't it be a 9 x 9 array of buttons?

Comment: sorry my mistake. both ways are correct It does not matter. But Array instantiation should be as I mentioned above

Comment: You are saying some problem? Which one -any exception ?

Comment: When I remove the buttons I still get the same problem the program compiling and running without doing anything but strangely enough when I add the buttons and do the changes I still get aNullPointerException. I addes the changes

Comment: In your code There is no code that removes button . Can you specify code snippet which cause Exception

Comment: What I meant by removing buttons is, just removing them from the code to test if the rest of the code works. grid[i][j].setLabel(s); in setText(String s, int i, int j) gives me the exception.

Comment: If you are getting NullPointerException then verify instantiation of all used references or proper sequence of usage of variable[e.g. variable declared  but used somewhere without instantiating it] or debug your application using debugger.

Comment: yea I think I know why, its giving me an error on new SudokuBoard(this); Why would that give an error? SudokuBoard's constructor takes SudokuGame so is there something wrong here?